# getting SPList data using HttpWebRequest

Tags: list, development, xml

I want to get SPlist data using HTTPWebRequest but not sure how can i do it, here's the code I made until now,

```
                // Create a web request to get the xml feed
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WEBURL);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password);

            XmlDocument xml = null;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // If the request/response is successful
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // Get the response stream containing the xml
                using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {}}
```

Cheers

Comment: what is your question anyway ;)?

Comment: LOL question is, my code is half complete, and I dont know how to get the data using this XML reader lol

Comment: Look at your tags! 2010/2007/list/xml/wtf? Which version of SharePoint are you actually using, 2007 or 2010?

Comment: sorry, 2007 is what i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what you're trying to do with that code but I'll make an attempt at guessing anyway.

If you're using SharePoint 2007 then the way to access list data via a 'http request' is using the [SharePoint web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390%28v=office.12%29).

[MSDN - HOW TO : Return List Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms429658%28v=office.12%29)

Comment: because I can't add web reference to a gadget , I will try using Javascript to do the same thing
http://vishsharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/get-sharepoint-list-data-using.html